# Reversing conditional distribution

Tags: probability, bayesian

I want to find $p(x \vert y)$ given $p(y \vert x)$. I am aware of Bayesian formula but I can not understand why the following logic is wrong.

Let $x$ some random variable with pdf $p(x)$ and $\varepsilon \sim N(0,1)$.

Define $y(x) \equiv x + \varepsilon$, then $(y\vert x) \sim N(x,1)$.

But it also should be true that $x=y-\varepsilon$ and because standard normal distribution is symmetric around zero, then it should follow that $(x \vert y) \sim N(y,1)$. Thus we didn't use the information about unconditional distributions, needed for Bayesian formula.

Please, point me where I am wrong.

**Update 1:** by Bayesian formula I mean $p(x \vert y) = \frac{p(y \vert x)p(x)}{\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}p(y \vert x)p(x)dx}$.

**Update 2:** The following analytical solution should prove that two distributions are indeed not equal.

Let $x \sim N(\mu,\sigma)$, then $p(x)=\frac{e^{-\frac{(x-\mu )^2}{2 \sigma ^2}}}{\sqrt{2 \pi } \sigma }$.

Let $y(x)=x+\varepsilon$ and $\varepsilon \sim N(0,1)$, then $p(y\vert x)=\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2} (y-x)^2}}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}$.
Hence, $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}p(y \vert x)p(x)dx=\frac{e^{-\frac{(y-\mu )^2}{2 \left(\sigma ^2+1\right)}}}{\sqrt{2 \pi } \sqrt{\frac{1}{\sigma ^2}+1} \sigma }$ and therefore by Bayesian formula $p(x\vert y)=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{\sigma ^2}+1} \exp \left(-\frac{(x-\mu )^2}{2 \sigma ^2}-\frac{1}{2} (y-x)^2+\frac{(y-\mu )^2}{2 \left(\sigma ^2+1\right)}\right)}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}$. Finally, this is not equal to pdf of $N(y,1)$, which is $\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2} (x-y)^2}}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}$.

Comment: How did you get the $f_Y(y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y)\ dx$ . There is a missing Erf in the numerator.

Comment: I did it with Wolfram Mathematica. For indefinite integral I have Erf. But because this integral is definite, Erf function takes particular values.

Comment: OK. OK. OK. OK ok.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I am not very helpful. For the indefinite integral I have $\frac{e^{-\frac{(y-\mu )^2}{2 \left(\sigma ^2+1\right)}} \text{erf}\left(\frac{-\mu +\sigma ^2 (x-y)+x}{\sqrt{2} \sigma  \sqrt{\sigma ^2+1}}\right)}{2 \sqrt{2 \pi } \sqrt{\sigma ^2+1}}$

Answer (score 1):

The best is to distinguish between random variables and values taken by them. So let me reformulate the question:

We have three random variables, $X$ and $$Y=X+\varepsilon,$$ and $\varepsilon$ is of $N(0,1)$. If we may, we assume that $X$ and $\varepsilon$ are independent. The conditional distribution of $Y$ given that $X=x$ is then, indeed $N(x,1)$.

On the other hand $$X=Y-\varepsilon$$

and let's calculate $X$'s conditional distribution given that $Y=y$.

$$F_{X\mid Y=y}(x)=P(X<x\mid X+\varepsilon=y)=P(X<x\mid X=y-\varepsilon)=$$
$$=P(y-\varepsilon<x\mid X=y-\varepsilon)=P(y-\varepsilon<x)$$
because of the independence of $X$ and $\varepsilon$. From here,

$$F_{X\mid Y=y}(x)=P(y-\varepsilon<x)=P(\varepsilon>y-x)=P(\varepsilon<x-y)$$
because of symmetry. And this is the distribution function of $N(y,1)$. So, there is no mistake.

The only thing is that independence had to be assumed. Also, the symmetric nature of $N(0,\sigma)$ was exploited.

---

**EDIT**

On the necessity of independence.

Let $\epsilon^-$ and $\epsilon^+$ be two random variables of "half normal $\pm$" distribution. The distributions are defined as follow

$$F_{\epsilon^+}(x)=\begin{cases}2N(0,1)(x)&\text{ if } x\geq 0\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$

($\epsilon^{-}$'s pdf is similar but it is $0$ for $x$s less than zero...) Also, assume that $\epsilon^{\pm}$ are independent of $X$. Now, assume that there is an $x_0>0$ so that $P(X<x_0)=P(X\geq x_0)=\frac 12$ and define $$\varepsilon=\begin{cases}\varepsilon^-&\text{ if }&X<x_0\\\epsilon^+&\text{ if }&X\geq x_0.\end{cases}.$$

The distribution of $\varepsilon$ is $N(0,1)$ but it is not independent from $X$.

Let't calculate $Y$'s conditional distribution given that $X=x$:

$$P(X+\epsilon<y\mid X=x)=P(\varepsilon<y-x\mid X=x)=\begin{cases}F_{\epsilon^-}(y-x)&\text{ if }& x<x_0\\ F_{\epsilon^+}(y-x)&\text{ if }& x\geq x_0.\end{cases}$$

For a given $x>x_0$ the conditional pdf of $Y$ looks like this[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate why independence is important?

Comment: Zoli, thank you very much for your comment. It put me on a right track. However, I simulated two pdf functions: one is computed using Bayesian formula with x distributed $N(\mu,\sigma)$ and one $N(y,1)$ and they are not equal.

Comment: @dart_kaide: In the OP, you had $N(0,1)$. If you have $N(\mu,\sigma)$ then the conditional pdfs is question are $N(\mu-x,1)$ and $N(\mu-y,1)$.

Comment: @kludg: I edited my answer.

Comment: Concerning the Edit: I am missing the point. I still think that the independence is not needed in the original post.

Comment: @kludg: The original post claims that one of the conditional pdf's is $N(x,1)$. This is not true if the distribution of $\epsilon$ is like in my EDIT.

Comment: Zoli, what I mean that $x \sim N(\mu, \sigma)$ which is used in the Bayesian formula.

Comment: actually I think that $\epsilon \sim N(0,1)$ is not important too, it is enough that the distribution is symmetric around zero.

Comment: @kludg: symmetry **and** independence are important.

Comment: Dear zoli, please check my Update 2.

Comment: @dart_kaide: Yes, as soon as I will have time, I will...

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the second part of the argument where you write $x=y-\varepsilon$. Because $y$ and $\varepsilon$ are not independent variables, $P_{X|Y}(x|y)$ is not just a shift of $P_\varepsilon$.

To convince yourself that is the source of the problem, think of the following argument:

If $y = x+\varepsilon$, and $x$ and $\varepsilon$ are independent variables, then $y$ will have a distribution with a variance larger than that of $x$.

If $x = y - \varepsilon$, and $y$ and $\varepsilon$ are independent variables, then $x$ will have a distribution with the larger variance.

Answer (score 0):

Take $f(x,y)=p(y|x)$ as given conditional PDF and $p_X{x}$ as PDF of $X$. therefore:

$$p(x,y)=p(y|x)p_X(x)\to p_Y(y)=\Sigma_x p(y|x)p_X(x)\to p(x|y)={{p(y|x)p_X(x)}\over{\Sigma_x p(y|x)p_X(x)}}$$

So this question requires extra information. Now using your method the question is:
"What if $\epsilon\nsim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$?"

Comment: Sorry, didn't help.

Comment: Why?..................

Comment: This is  $\epsilon\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$?

Comment: Try $\epsilon\sim Uniform(0,1)$ and you obtain another answer....

Comment: I would like to have normal distribution and to see why it shouldn't work

Comment: Then it works why shouldn't? But I don't think to be the most general case...

Comment: Because numerical simulation shows that it is not...

Answer (score 0):

Let's clean up notation first; I will use $Z$ instead of $\varepsilon$. We have 2 **independent** random variables $X$ and $Z$. To simplify the following I'll assume that $X$ and $Z$ are **discrete**. Now we define $Y=X+Z$

The conditional PMF of $Y$ given $X$ is 
$$p_{Y|X}(y|x)=P(Y=y|X=x)=P(X+Z=y|X=x)=P(x+Z=y)=P(Z=y-x)=p_Z(y-x)$$
so the conditional PMF $p_{Y|X}(y|x)$ if the same as $p_Z(y)$ shifted right by $x$.

The conditional PMF of $X$ given $Y$ is 
$$p_{X|Y}(x|y)=P(X=x|Y=y)=P(Y-Z=x|Y=y)$$

We can't proceed from here to

$$P(Y-Z=x|Y=y) \overset{?}{=} P(y-Z=x)=P(Z=y-x)=p_Z(y-x)$$

because $Y=X+Z$ and $Z$ are **dependent**.

Comment: $p_{Y|X}(y|x)=P(Y=y|X=x)=P(X+Z=y|X=x)=P(x+Z=y)=P(Z=y-x)=p_Z(y-x)$ . This is true in general if $X$ and $Z$ are independent. See, my counterexample.

Comment: @zoli I still think there is no reason why it should fail if $X$ and $Z$ are dependent.

Comment: Do you understand my counterexample? Does it not show you that, if $X$ and $Z$ are dependent then the resulting conditional distribution is not equal to the shifted distribution of $Z$?

Comment: @zoli your counterexample is not symmetric; and yes, I don't understand it.

Comment: The distribution of $Z$, in my example, is $N(0,1)$, so it is symmetric.

Comment: @zoli OK, I don't understand your counterexample, and since I can't see how things may possibly change if $X$ and $Z$ are dependent, I think that independence is not needed.

Comment: Look, this is a dangerous position: not understanding something and yet opposing it... But I would go back to your statement: $P(Y-Z=x|Y=y)=P(y-Z=x)$ without independence. This is false. You can substitute $y$ for $Y$ but you cannot omit the condition if $Y$ and $Z$ are dependent.

Comment: @zoli Now I've got it, thanks! I implicitly replaced conditional probability by marginal, and it works only if random variables are independent. Editing the post now...

Comment: Very god decision!

Comment: Dear kludg, please check my Update 2.